# How can I grey out an image or list item with jQuery, but leave the image or list item clickable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

We are building an interface for a product catalogue where a group of products will be selectable by choosing from a number of options.  Options will be displayed as either images or list items (with a border/box around them).

When an option is clicked in a group of options, I would like to grey out options in the other groups of options that no longer apply due to the clicked option being chosen to filter the options.  I still want these greyed out options to be clickable, so that the filtering can be done by clicking on any of the options.

I know this can be done through jQuery and CSS, but what specific CSS should I be setting, and will it work the same for both the image and the list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

```
opacity: .5;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JEM2r/)